# I have to press Ctrl + Caps Lock to activate Caps Lock

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have Windows 10 home. For some reason in order to either activate or deactivate caps lock I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. How can I change it so I only have to press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to activate and deactivate it?

Comment: I suspect this has to be due to your keyboard layout.  Can you tell us more about the laptop?

Comment: This would occur on most machines if Caps Lock were on a key with two functions that are controlled by a Function Lock command on the keyboard.  Most keyboards have Caps Lock on its own and do not require an extra key

Comment: If this also happens when booting in Safe mode, then this is just how your keyboard works.